# Ninject configuration - generics

Tags: ninject

I have a group of base repositories that are setup like this ...

```
Bind<IRepository<SomeObject>>().To<SomeObjectRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("connection", connection);
Bind<IRepository<SomeOtherObject>>().To<SomeOtherObjectRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("connection", connection);
//and so on
```

Those repositories are simple - the whole class goes as such.

```
public class SomeObjectRepository : Repository<SomeObject>
{
    public SomeObjectRepository (string connection) : base(connection)
    {
    }
}
```

So I thought, hey that's kinda dumb, so I created a generic base repository and replaced all those bindings with this.

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>)).WithConstructorArgument("connection", connection);
```

which of course broke and got hit with an error

> Error activating
>   IRepository{SomeObject} using binding
>   from IRepository{T} to Repository{T}
>   No constructor was available to create
>   an instance of the implementation
>   type.

Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Can you provide the Repository<> implementation? especially the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but you need to be binding IRepository to SomeObjectRepository.